# What did I miss here in the solution for TWO SUMS problem?

Tags: python

> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target. You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice. You can return the answer in any order.

Example 1:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9

Output: [0,1]

Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].

My solution in python was:

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for a in nums:
        for b in nums:
            s=a+b
            if s==target:
                if nums.index(a) != nums.index(b):
                    return nums.index(a),nums.index(b)
```

Result was 47/ 54 test cases passed.

The error was in the following testcase:

```
Input:
[3,3]
6

Output:
[]

Expected:
[0,1]
```

Could you tell me what I've missed here?

Comment: "you may not use the same element twice" you also have to check for index/value equality

Comment: You might consider using `itertools.permutations` to get the list of non-duplicate entries.  It's a little bit of overkill for this problem, but it makes things easy.

Comment: What do you mean by "tell me what I've missed"?  You missed clearly stated problem specification.  We expect you to perform the basic code tracing before your post, which makes the problem clear: when the outer loop selects value that happens to be half of the target, then you must exclude that from the inner loop.

Comment: The index() method only returns the first occurrence of the matching element.

Comment: Seems like you can assume that `nums` is sorted in increasing order (and trivially if `nums` wasn't, you could just sort it). Then to programmatically enforce the requirement *"you may not use the same element twice"*, if you use index i you can't also use index (i+1) when `nums[i] == nums[i+1]` i.e. if its left-neighbor has the same value.

Comment: FYI there are 10 Q&A on [*"two sums" LeetCode*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22two+sums%22+leetcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nums.index(a) would return the first index it finds a on.
So for [3, 3], it would always return 0, even though nums[1] is also 3.
You should rather use indexes and start the second loop from the 1 + current index of the first loop

```
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
            s=num[i]+nums[j]
            if s==target:
                return [i, j]
```